# Fragment is not shown from only one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
    public void handleChangeFragment(View view) {
        Log.e("123","123");
        Fragment selectedFragment;
        if(view == findViewById(R.id.dairy)){
            selectedFragment = new milkFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(view == findViewById(R.id.meat)){
            selectedFragment = new meatFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(view == findViewById(R.id.veg)){
            selectedFragment = new vegFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(view == findViewById(R.id.orders)){
            selectedFragment = new ordersFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(view == findViewById(R.id.you)){
            selectedFragment = new youFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }else if(view == findViewById(R.id.cart)){
            Log.e("23","23");
            selectedFragment = new cartFragment();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if(view == findViewById(R.id.selected)){
            if(selectedText.getText().equals("Dairy")){
                selectedFragment = new milkFragment();
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else if(selectedText.getText().equals("Meat")){
                selectedFragment = new meatFragment();
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else if(selectedText.getText().equals("Vegetable")){
                selectedFragment = new vegFragment();
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, selectedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is this, the cart is not clickable means  when currently opened fragment is Dairy, from the rest it is. It enters the handleChangeFragment() but somehow lost path during journey to R.id.cart. If someone has solution then kindly share.
Here is the snap of activity.

[image]

Comment: man, your 4 last lines of all conditions are the same! you could simply put all of them after the whole if, and just check if the selected fragment isn't null, do the transaction. and for your problem i think you should show us HOW and WHEN u implement the cart's on click listener if u are not using BottomNavigation and if u do, what happens in the Diary that is realted to the cart

Comment: Thanks for your correctness. In xml file, I have set the onClick of all parent views top and botton navigation(wraps imageview and textview) which are relativelayout in my case  to handleChangeFragment(), and called it like above from activity.

Comment: are u using something for the cart's green badge icon?

Comment: yeah textview with background drawable.

Comment: are u using Bottom Navigation View?

Comment: no <cardview<gridlayout<linearlayout<finallyrelativelayout which wraps imageview and textview.

Comment: i cant understand where is the problem, maybe because setting the onclick in the xml is not updated when the fragment is changed and it considers the previous onclick function on the previous fragment. i suggest u to use bottom navigation view: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-bottom-navigation-bar-for-an-android-app--cms-30305